# Dynamic choice field excluding objects over a certain amount of entries

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to return a list of dates for a form based on the current amount of bookings in a model.

The current threshold is set at 6, so If 6 bookings already exist it will exclude it from the list of dates available.

Here's my current code

```
def get_available_dates():
    dates = next_x_months(12)
    weds = [last_wednesday(year, month) for year, month in dates]
    choices = list()
    for i, wed in enumerate(weds):
        booking_total = Booking.objects.filter(booking_date=wed)
        total = booking_total.count()
        if total >= 6:
            weds.pop(i)
        else:
            choices.append((wed, wed,))
    return choices


class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    booking_choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_available_dates())
    ...
```

`weds` returns the following:

```
[datetime.date(2018, 1, 31), datetime.date(2018, 2, 28), datetime.date(2018, 3, 28), datetime.date(2018, 4, 25), datetime.date(2018, 5, 30), datetime.date(2018, 6, 27), datetime.date(2018, 7, 25), datetime.date(2018, 8, 29), datetime.date(2018, 9, 26), datetime.date(2018, 10, 31), datetime.date(2018, 11, 28), datetime.date(2018, 12, 26)]
```

Now, I have some test data in my model. There are 6 entries for `31/1/2018`, and 2 entries for `28/2/2018`.

However, what `get_available_dates()` is returning drops the `31/1/2018` date (as it should) but also drops `28/2/2018` which it shouldn't. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: This is not an MCVE, so I can only guess.  But this: `weds.pop(i)` is suspicious. It is often a bad idea to modify the iterable that you are using for the loop, in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As highlighted by Stephen. Turns out I was getting the undesired behavior by modifying the loop variable inside of the loop. (In my defense, it was 3 am and I should have known better).

Modifying the loop variable inside of the loop caused the index to shift, as it was the first item in the loop variable that was removed, the second date which in this case was `28/2/2018` then shifted to index `0` and index `1` became `28/3/2018` and as the iteration was then at `1` this shift caused the output to skip index `0`.

```
def get_available_dates():
    dates = next_x_months(12)
    weds = [last_wednesday(year, month) for year, month in dates]
    choices = list()
    for i, wed in enumerate(weds):
        booking_total = Booking.objects.filter(booking_date=wed)
        total = booking_total.count()
        if total < 6:
            choices.append((wed, wed,))            
    return choices
```

The above code solved the issue.